# html in varchar field?

Tags: mysql, html

I have a varchar(255) field in mysql that is used for displaying the title to a page and I received a request to superscript some characters for a particular title. I updated this title with some html but this doesn't render as expected.

Instead of H<sup>2</sup>O I get:

```
H<sup>2</sup>O
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is means you can't add HTML tags in your database, because they are escaped while printing onto web-page. Otherwise it can be security problem if you allow your user to write any HTML code into web-page.

Comment: And what is your question specifically?

Comment: That sounds like what is going on, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, you can't use HTML tags to highlight your title.

HOWEVER! You *can* use unicode literals.

Try this:

```
H&#178;O
```

The `&#178` is the unicode character for the superscripted 2.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) wikipedia article to see what superscripts and subscripts you can play with, and bear in mind that the U+xyz form is in hexadecimal, but the &#abc; form in HTML requires decimal values. U+b2 is &#178 in HTML.

Answer (score 4):

This is unrelated to MySQL, the browser chooses to render it this way. Via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Document_structure_elements

> The title element must not contain
>   other elements, only text.

Answer (score 0):

That means you have either [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)ed or [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities)ed the text, either on input or on output.

(If you're talking about something like a `<h1>` tag in the pages `<body>`, at least. Otherwise the other answerer is right.)